# Ignoring method calls in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

With Mockito, is it possible to ignore a method call to a mock?

E.g. for the mock `rugger` created with `mock(MyRugger.class)`:

```
class Pepe {

  public void runner() {     
    rugger.doIt(); 
    rugger.flushIt();
    rugger.boilIt();     
  } 
}
```

I need only test `runner()` but avoid the method `flushIt()`.

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? Not check? Ignore a call to it? Not mock it?

Comment: That edit changes things a little. How is your class passed `rugger`?

Comment: I mean the instance variable, `rugger`. How does it get into each instance. Is it passed in through a constructor, a setter, or is it internally created?

Answer (score 4):

To reset a mock in Mockito, simply call [`reset`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) on it. Note the very real concern mentioned in the above link and the [JavaDoc for `reset`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#reset%28T...%29) stating that it may represent bad design.

This should generally be avoided, but there are times when you simply need to do this. The below is an example on how to use it, *not* a good example of when to use it.

```
Object value = mock(Object.class);

when(value.equals(null)).thenReturn(true);
assertTrue(value.equals(null));
verify(value).equals(null);

reset(value);

assertFalse(value.equals(null));
verify(value).equals(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Mockito is nice and will not verify calls unless you ask it to.  So if you don't want to verify `flush()` just verify the methods you care about:

```
verify(rugger).doIt();
verify(rugger).boilIt();
```

If you want to verify that `flush()` was NOT called, use:

```
verify(rugger, never()).flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ignoreStub method. See documentation here:

http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html